# stored procedures search elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to script a recursive search in elastic.
i know there are search-templates,but i am not finding examples like below scenario

```
 `ex:-father= neo
  1.search in person-index documents for father attribute
  2.if father=neo return direct,else(here father=ted)
  3.search for ted now and check if father=neo return indirect 
  or repeat step 3 till script find's ancestor if not found return not related when reached father = some constant like (pre-genator or ancient)
  `
```

This eliminates for me to go for graph database, if i have only one relation .
 another scenario like find all decedents of "neo"

Answer (score 2):

There is no facility to do exactly what you are describing inside elasticsearch at the moment.

If number of ancestral generations is limited and they can be expressed as 1-to-many relationships, you can use multiple has_parent queries.

Alternatively, if it's possible, you can denormalize the data and store names of all ancestors for the given record in a single field. So the record would look like this:

```
{
  "father": "neo",
  "ancestors": ["neo", "ted", ... ]
}
```

Otherwise, you need to do these searches outside of elasticsearch.

Comment: ya, i was thinking of that scenario, the problem is maintaining the data.